# How to use my own Jquery in Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am new at Laravel, I have to add a **Jquery**  to my code how do I add this?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectAll').on('click',function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.chkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
            $('.chkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    })
});
```

> If I am creating a file named `myjquery.js`

- Where do I add this file?
- How should I link this? or any other method to add above code?

Comment: What do you mean "where shoudl I add this"? In <script> tags in your view, maybe? :) same where you put the jQuery library

Comment: you can use both no problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to append it inside  `<script></script>` tags and **after including** the jquery library.

If you include them both (your script and the jquery library) at the end of your page, right before the closing `</body>` tag, even better, because of usability reasons.

**My advice**:

Add this at the bottom of your main template:

```
.
.
.
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            @yield('postJquery');
        });
    </script>
    </body></html>
```

so that you ensure the jQuery library and subsequent javascript scripts are loaded at the end.

And then, add this in the view that needs your script and that extends your main template :

```
@section('postJquery')
    @parent
    $('#selectAll').on('click',function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.chkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
            $('.chkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
@endsection
```

So that your script is only included in the view that actually needs it. You can do this for any script you need. The `@parent` part is needed to prevent the overwriting of the `postJquery` section with a partial view casted by your a view already using the same section.

Answer (score 4):

You can load this file in you public folder, Like, `public/js/myjquery.js`

It can be loaded in `blade` file like,

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/myjquery.js') }}"></script>
```